# Distance Between Markers - no result on first click

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an app that adds a 50mi radius around the current/clicked marker (from mapMarkers[]).  I know the selected marker's index number and its LatLng position  as "myPosition" and the other markers' LatLng position as mapMarkers[i].point.

After the circle is drawn on the map, I call the following simple function to step thru all the mapMarkers[] to compute the distance from the current marker, and then count how many markers actually fall within the 50mi radius.  Simple, right?

Problem:  The following routine does not produce any result upon first iteration (i.e., first click) for the current marker.  But DOES produce the expected result upon the 2nd and subsequent clicks on the current marker.

```
function inCircle() {
    var j = 0;
    var myDistance = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {
        myDistance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myPosition, mapMarkers[i].point);
        myDistance = parseInt(myDistance/1609.34)  //meters to miles
        if (myDistance <= 50) {
            j = j + 1;
            //Do more stuff...
        }
    }
    alert("Markers inside circle: " + j);
}
```

I call this function just after I BIND the circle to the selected marker. "myPosition" is declared as the map loads.  Commenting-out the distance calculations produces results on the first iteration for the current marker.

Any thoughts what might be causing this issue?

Comment: I think, the geometry library is only loading because you made a request. see here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries .Have you included the geometry-spherical library when you call the google maps js(during page load)?

Comment: I did not...and that DOES solve the issue!  Thanks~

Comment: Great! I'll post it an an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WRT my comment above: I think, the geometry library is only loading because you made a request. see here developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries. Include the geometry-spherical library when you call the google maps js(during page load).

Eg:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing,geometry,weather"></script>
```